# jquery : $.parseHTML is not working to submit the form from remote file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form submission problem

I am submitting a paypal form using the following method: I am retrieving the paypal form using jquery and using parseHTML I am submitting the form. This works fine in chrome but not in firefox. Any needs more information please ask me.
paypalsubmit is the id of the remote form
payment.php contains the paypal form

```
  $.post("payment.php",{payment:"paypal"}).done(function(data){

      setTimeout(function(){$($.parseHTML(data)).find("#paypalsubmit").submit();},4000);
  });
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you include text of  `data` at Question?

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: @marsze it's not submitting the form

Comment: @guest271314 it's normal working form, I think there is no problem in the form

Comment: I think that was obvious. Is there a JS error? Where does the script stop. Did you debug it?

Comment: @marsze there is no error

Comment: @scriptkiddie _"it's normal working form, I think there is no problem in the form"_ Can you include text of form, `data` at Question?, create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce issue?